# Is there a term for a flaw in logic?

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

I write code for a living and I'm trying to find the right word for a flaw in logic.  "Error" seems too vague, I'm looking specifically for a word that describes a flaw in logic.

Addendum 1: This would be an unintended flaw in logic.
Addendum 2: Preferably 1 word, please.

Comment: If Mr. Hen's answer isn't what you are looking for, then you might want to consider giving an example or two. Some examples of logical fallacies would be:Affirming the consequent: the antecedent in an indicative conditional is claimed to be true because the consequent is true; if A, then B; B, therefore A.
Denying the antecedent: the consequent in an indicative conditional is claimed to be false because the antecedent is false; if A, then B; not A, therefore not B.

Comment: @Kevin Think, man, think! The OP can't go into a functional spec review and talk about "logical fallacies!" He'd be hooted from the room :-)

Comment: @Pete, I completely glossed over the "I write code" part.

Comment: What's an _intended_ flaw...in anything?

Comment: @Mitch: Sabotage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the point of view, doesn't it?

When someone finds a logic error in my code, I call it "a small misunderstanding" and blame it on marketing's requirements doc.

When I find a logic error in somebody else's code, I call it "a total fsck()ing disaster!" and blame it on management's hiring policies.

**In general, though, "bug" is not only the right word; it's the only word.** You can't go wrong with "bug" in any context having to do with code.

Answer (score 6):

A "logical fallacy" [means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logical_fallacy):

> Clearly defined error in reasoning used to support or refute an argument, excluding simple unintended mistakes.

Wikipedia provides a good [list of fallacies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy). You may be able to find a more descriptive term for whatever error you happened across.

Response to addendum: "Fallacy" works fine on its own. Fallacies imply nothing about intention and context will clue people into the implicit "logic" topic. If that doesn't do it for you, here are a few other options:

- irrational
- illogic
- mistake
- accident

If you are looking for a term to use in class or variable names, "flaw" or "error" would probably be fine with some good supporting documentation describing the problem. `logicError` is certainly legible.

Comment: Sure, I added an addendum

Answer (score 4):

It may seem too easy but

> logical flaw

or

> logical error

works, to distinguish it from other flaws  or errors (like typos or errors of fact).

Comment: I was hoping for a one word answer, but maybe the English language doesn't include what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are single words for different kinds of errors: typo (for transcription error), lacuna (missing info), solecism (a grammatical error), untrue (a factual error), fallacy (an error in argumentation, of which a particular kind is a logical fallacy (back to where we started))...but I can't find a single word for 'logical error'. As succinct as single words are, a two word version can say what it means just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

How about "illogicality"? I just made it up, but then I googled it, and it already existed!

I can't find a specific definition for it, but it's listed as a noun under "illogical" in several dictionaries....So, most basic definition would be "a thing that is illogical."